# Getting error "Reference air.sdk.path.linux.3.9 not found " in ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, flash, gradle, apache-flex

I am trying to build a project with `gradlefx` . During the build i am getting following exception error .

```
get-data:
[get] Getting: http://flex.apache.org/installer/sdk-installer-config-4.0.xml
[get] To: /home/ubuntu/.gradle/gradleFx/sdks/86c6aa5c2c1084d7f4e8996be5c5cfa2e429cbe9/sdk-installer-config-4.0.xml

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'dashas-master'.
The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/ubuntu/.gradle/gradleFx/sdks/86c6aa5c2c1084d7f4e8996be5c5cfa2e429cbe9/installer.xml:119: Reference air.sdk.path.linux.3.9 not found.
```

I don't know why the gradle is not downloading the file . I can clearly seen the version `air.sdk.path.linux.2.6` from the following XML file .

from : http://flex.apache.org/installer/sdk-installer-config-4.0.xml

```
<linux>
<versions default="2.6">
<versionA id="air.sdk.version.linux.2.6" version="2.6" displayVersion="2.6">
<server id="air.sdk.server.linux.2.6">http://airdownload.adobe.com</server>
<folder id="air.sdk.folder.linux.2.6">air/lin/download/2.6/</folder>
<path id="air.sdk.path.linux.2.6">http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/2.6/</path>
<file id="air.sdk.file.linux.2.6">AdobeAIRSDK.tbz2</file>
</versionA>
</versions>
</linux>
```

Anything wrong here ? Please Suggest me any methods to resolve this type of error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Myself I have found the solution . we can compile the project with specifying air.sdk.version=2.6 `-Dair.sdk.version=2.6` . We can build by command

```
gradle clean compile -Dair.sdk.version=2.6
```